# Joining tables in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I have a query below, How can recreate this one to join the tables that will return a list of `SurveyProjectNormDTO` using NHibernate? Any help please?

```
              using (var session = OpenSession()){

                var projectGroupIds = session.Query<ReportingStructureNodeProjectGroups>()
                    .Where(x => x.NodeID == nodeId);

                    projectGroupIds.Fetch(x => x.ProjectGroupID).ToFuture();


                var projectIds = session.Query<ProjectGroup>().Where(p => projectGroupIds.Contains(p.Id));


                projectIds.Fetch(x => x.ProjectID).ToFuture();

                var projectNormProjects = session.Query<SurveyProjectNorm>().Where(x => projectIds.Contains(x.SurveyProjectId));

                projectNormProjects.Fetch(x => x.ShortLabels).ToFuture();
                projectNormProjects.Fetch(x => x.ReportingNames).ToFuture();
                projectNormProjects.Fetch(x => x.NormProject).ToFuture();

                var response = new List<SurveyProjectNormDTO>();

                projectNormProjects.ToList().ForEach(
                    p =>
                    {
                        response.Add(
                            new SurveyProjectNormDTO { Id = p.Id, ProjectName = p.NormProject.ProjectName, ReportingName = p.ReportingNames.Select(s => s.LocalizedText).FirstOrDefault() });
                    });

                return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if these `let` commands will work fine but you can try this. It will do a single hit on the database fetching the properties. Test it and let us know if it works.

```
var queryResult  = (from p in session.Query<SurveyProjectNorm>()
            let projectGroupIds = session.Query<ReportingStructureNodeProjectGroups>().Where(x => x.NodeID == nodeId).Select(x => x.Id)
            let projectIds = session.Query<ProjectGroup>().Where(x => projectGroupIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Id)
            where projectIds.Contains(p.SurveyProjectId)
            select p)
              .Fetch(x => x.ShortLabels)
              .Fetch(x => x.ReportingNames)
              .Fetch(x => x.NormProject)
              .ToList();

var response = new List<SurveyProjectNormDTO>();

queryResult.ForEach(p =>
    response.Add(new SurveyProjectNormDTO { 
            Id = p.Id, 
            ProjectName = p.NormProject.ProjectName, 
            ReportingName = p.ReportingNames.Select(s => s.LocalizedText).FirstOrDefault() }));


return result;
```